# RN42 Bluetooth module datasheet parameter for average power consumption during data transfer

Tags: power, datasheet, bluetooth

I've attached a picture from a datasheet (RN42 Bluetooth module) that I've been looking at. The amount of current specified for transmit is 45 mA, is this per a packet of data sent? So to send 1 Mbyte of data it would draw 45A!?!?! Sounds stupid but what is the 45 mA relational to?

[image]

Comment: Current doesn't accumulate over time; the device just draws 45mA while it's transmitting. Energy is cumulative.

Answer (score 1):

No, it means that while you are transmitting data, it draws 45 mA from the power supply. The maximum transfer rate is 3Mbps, so it takes about 1/3 second to send 1Mbit of data. Under this 1/3 second the current consumption of the module is 45mA.

Comment: but that implies that it would also me 45mA energy consumption if the data transfer were lasting for the full second.